# Как запустить команду вместе с запуском cmd

Tags: windows, cmd

Мне нужно сделать так, что-бы после нажатий клавиш win + r открывается окно "выполнить" так вот, в это окно выполнить я вставляю команду cmd, что открывает командную строку, могу ли я сразу написать команду туда же, то есть например cmd "команда, например winver" и после этого открывается командная строка с этой же командой

Comment: извиняюсь в том что длинно, прост по другому я написать не могу

Comment: Набери `CMD /?` и внимательно изучи.

Comment: а что означает "открывается командная строка с этой же командой"? Открывается консоль и в строке уже написана эта команда? Или открывается консоль и в ней сразу же выполняется введеная команда? Или что-то еще другое?

Answer (score 0):

1. win + r
2. cmd /?

появится спиок как можно выполнить команду